# c++ assignment operator between pointer and double

Tags: c++

I have a class which has member variables which are pointers to another class

```
struct Unit {
    Unit();
    double value;
}

struct Widget {
    Widget();
    Unit *width;
}

Unit::Unit(){
    value = 0.0;
}

Widget::Widget(){
    width = new Unit();
}
```

I would like to overload the assignment operator so that this:

```
Widget w;
w.width = 4.0;
```

Will set the Widget's `width`'s `value` to 4. I think the answer is in friend functions but I am not familiar enough with them to achieve this.

Just for clarity, the operator overload would be equivalent to this:

```
w.width->value = 4.0;
```

Comment: You use references for this, not pointers. And then define the assignment operator in `Unit`. And I was also going to say what @MooingDuck wrote: Always prefer values if there is no particular reason for a reference/pointer.

Comment: Or values. Even better than references. Because right now, Widget violates the rule of three, which will cause random things to happen.

Comment: @eukaryota They need to be pointers, that's part of the question :)

Comment: `w.width` is a pointer, so no overload is going to change anything, without changing the syntax.  The best will be `w.setWidth(4.0)` or `w.width = new Unit(4.0);`. Unless you change `width` to no longer be a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CAN define an overloaded operator that would let you do something like

```
Widget w;
w = 4.0;
```

and have it internally set *width to 4.0 (with the obvious need to check to be sure the pointer isn't bad). As mentioned above, you'd be better off not using a pointer for that reason, though.

What you can NOT do, though, is exactly as you asked, as it would require overloading operator= to work between a pointer and a float. see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/intrinsic-types#intrinsics-and-operator-overloading

Comment: Interesting, I didn't consider the pointer to a class as an intrinsic for some reason. I gave in and just started dereferencing the objects, which does the trick. `*w.width = 3.0;`